# Grouping consecutive sequences of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to group consecutive rows where a boolean value is true on SQL Server. For example, here's what some source data looks like:

```
AccountID | ID | IsTrue | Date
-------------------------------
1         | 1  | 1      | 1/1/2013
1         | 2  | 1      | 1/2/2013
1         | 3  | 1      | 1/3/2013
1         | 4  | 0      | 1/4/2013
1         | 5  | 1      | 1/5/2013
1         | 6  | 0      | 1/6/2013
1         | 7  | 1      | 1/7/2013
1         | 8  | 1      | 1/8/2013
1         | 9  | 1      | 1/9/2013
```

And here's what I'd like as the output

```
AccountID | Start    | End
-------------------------------
1         | 1/1/2013 | 1/3/2013
1         | 1/7/2013 | 1/9/2013
```

I have a hunch that there's some trick with grouping by partitions that will make this work but I've been unable to figure it out. I've made some progress using LAG but haven't been able to put it all together.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How is the result set defined?

Comment: Why isn't there a 3rd group of one row, for the 5th of Jan?

Comment: Lets see the progress you made using `lag`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a gaps and islands problem.  For this version, you just need a sequential number for each `isTrue`.  Subtracting this number of days from each date is a constant for adjacent values that are the same:

```
select accountId, isTrue, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by accountId, isTrue order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by accountId, isTrue, dateadd(day, -seqnum, date);
```

This defines all groups.  If I assume that you just want values of "1" that are more than 1 day long, then:

```
select accountId, isTrue, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by accountId, isTrue order by date) as seqnum
      from t
      where isTrue = 1
     ) t
group by accountId, isTrue, dateadd(day, -seqnum, date)
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gN6kTUot3uLSF7jLaQSmuG/0). I have assumption that `id` will always have consecutive values.

```
with cte as
(
  select
    *,
    count(*) over (partition by IsTrue, rnk) as total
  from
  (
      select
          *,
          id - row_number() over (partition by IsTrue order by id, date) as rnk
      from myTable
  ) val
)

select
    accountId,
    min(date) as start,
    max(date) as end
from cte
where total > 1
group by
    accountId,
    rnk
```

Output:

```
| accountid | start      | end        |
| --------- | ---------- | -----------|
| 1         | 2013-01-01 | 2013-01-03 |
| 1         | 2013-01-07 | 2013-01-09 |
```

Comment: You really should state the assumption that `id` will always have consecutive values for any given query (no gaps), as without conforming to that assumption the code simply would not work correctly.  Given the presence of the `accountID` column, that appears to be unlikely to be true outside of this limited example.  *(This query is likey to be on a per-account basis, and it is likely the IDs for each account would interleave with each other.)*

Comment: @MatBailie thanks for the feedback, I have thought but did not mentioned it in the solution, I have updated now.